# html document truncated in iis using jakarta connector to tomcat

Tags: tomcat, iis, isapi

We have a website which is hosted via IIS (Version 6.2 Windows Server 2012) and uses a jakarta connector isapi filter (isapi_redirect.dll) to route traffic to a Tomcat container on an application server. Recently we have discovered that some of our larger html files are being truncated.

We tested delivering the files using IIS only and the files are full length. We tested retrieving the files directly from the tomcat server over http and they are full length. Only when the jakarta connector is involved do we see the problem.

My theory based on the above is that the problem must lay either with the isapi_redirect.dll (which is the most recent version) or the fact that it is using ajp13 instead of http, but after hours looking through documentation, I am still scratching my head.

Has anyone else had this experience?

Comment: Microsoft only supports its customers if they use HttpPlatformHandler to run Java apps, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/manjug/2015/11/27/understanding-iis-httpplatformhandler-using-tomcat-8/

Comment: Thanks Lex, looks like the link you supplied has been removed. Could you provide a correct link?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/httpplatformhandler/httpplatformhandler-configuration-reference and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/blog/announcing-the-release-of-the-httpplatformhandler-module-for-iis-8/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem using Application Request Routing which can be installed in iis using the web platform handler. Here is a quick blog post describing the solution: https://blogs.sap.com/2014/11/05/how-to-configure-iis-arr-application-request-routing-to-redirect-to-tomcat/